# What is the Path to Learn BDD on Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I want to start BDD on Ruby On Rails what should I learn?
I don't know anything about BDD, RSpec or Cucumber. What is the best way to learn? Tutorials? Something that cover things like 'What behavior I should test?' etc.

thanks!

Comment: Here you can find all the rspec testcase examples.
Visit https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs and https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSpec specific; I keep these links for reference (might be advance for beginners). But just wanna share it with you. (Some of it probably already outdated but I think still worth a read)

[Rspec Link Fest - links to other references](http://www.decodeuri.com/2008/10/02/rspec-link-fest/)

RSpec in Controllers:
[Testing your Application Controller with rSpec](http://www.movesonrails.com/articles/2008/01/23/spec-ing-your-application-controller)

[Testing Controllers with rspec](http://www.elevatedrails.com/articles/2007/09/10/testing-controllers-with-rspec/)

[Using Rspec on Controllers](http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Using_Rspec_on_Controllers)

RSpec in Models:
[stub_model by Dave Chelimsky](http://www.nabble.com/stub_model-ts16120964.html)

[Do we really need Controller and View tests? - some discussion](http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/05/14/do-we-really-need-controller-and-view-tests)

RSpec in Views:

[RSpec testing views for escaped HTML](http://blog.wolfman.com/articles/2007/07/06/rspec-testing-views-for-escaped-html)

Rspec Stories (now Cucumber):

[Understanding RSpec Stories - a Tutorial](http://blog.emson.co.uk/2008/06/understanding-rspec-stories-a-tutorial/)

Rspec on Windows:

[RSpec, autotest and Snarl on Windows - dunno if this still relevant](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2007/12/10/rspec-autotest-and-snarl-on-windows)

p/s: Some are from 2007, I'm not sure if the stuffs are outdated or not, but these are the some of my references used to learn RSpec. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Start with two articles by Dan North: [Introducing BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd), followed closely [What's in a Story?](http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story)

Answer (score -1):

Start at the top, RSpec home page:

http://rspec.info/

Comment: -1 this is not helpful at all, just a link to a book with no explanation of what you find useful there. there is only one simple example on the page.