# Good resource to learn BDD, TDD (ruby , C#, javascript)

Tags: c#, javascript, ruby, tdd, bdd

What are the good resource to learn BDD & TDD (ruby , C#, javascript).

What are the good framework using now?

Answer (score 8):

See

- [Why should I practice Test Driven Development and how should I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303/why-should-i-practice-test-driven-development-and-how-should-i-start)
- [Beginning TDD - Challenges? Solutions? Recommendations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965/beginning-tdd-challenges-solutions-recommendations)
- [Good C# Unit testing book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509445/good-c-unit-testing-book/509464)
- [Introducing BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd)
- [What is the Path to Learn BDD on Ruby On Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485893/what-is-the-path-to-learn-bdd-on-ruby-on-rails)
- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)
- [Hanselminutes - Understanding BDD and NSpec](http://www.hanselminutes.com/294/understanding-bdd-and-nspec-with-matt-florence-and-amir-rajan)

Answer (score 2):

I can't really speak with too much authority on this subject, nor will I speak with too greater vigour given how storongly people feel about those two acronyms but it seams as though you are new to BDD / TDD so I will tell you what I wish someonehad told me when I first encoubtered them.

Tests and tools are one component of the overall process and methodology behind TDD, it is arguably one of the more visible aspects and so it is likely that you will see a lot of references to testing being an importabt part of TDD, and it is, I'm just saying, if you are interested in learning about TDD, don't forget the other aspects of it as well.

Resources I have found helpful:

- The Pragmatic Programmer: doesn't
  really talk about TDD per se, but it
  does emphisise a lot of other good
  practices that will help you.

Hanselminutes Episode 169

Tools I find helpful

- TestDriven.NET - test runner in
  visual studio
- xUnit.NET - Test Framework
- Rhino Mocks - Isolation (mocking)
  framework

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links that may be helpful to you.

- [What is the most mature BDD Framework for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307895/what-is-the-most-mature-bdd-framework-for-net)
- [Introduction to BDD and Mocking](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/introduction-to-behavior-driven-development-and-mocking)
- [BDD using NUnit and Moq](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/behavior-driven-development-in-dot-net-using-nunit-and-moq)
- [RSpec vs Cucumber (RSpec stories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393622/rspec-vs-cucumber-rspec-stories)
- [BDD with Cucumber and rspec - when is this redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736808/bdd-with-cucumber-and-rspec-when-is-this-redundant)
- [NSpec Project Site](http://nspec.org)
- [Continuous Testing](http://www.nspec.org/continuoustesting)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best way to learn these days is with plurasight

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/

my boss pays for me and my fellow developer to access the videos, but even if he didnt, its thats good id pay for it myself.